# What is the meaning of SimpleJdbcCall being "multi-threaded"?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-data

The doc for SimpleJdbcCall says [says](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.M1_to_4.2.0.M2/Spring%20Framework%204.0.0.M1/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcCall.html):

> A SimpleJdbcCall is a multi-threaded, reusable object representing a
> call to a stored procedure or a stored function.

Take the following code:

```
class A{
   
   private SimpleJdbcCall call;

   public void doSomething(){
       call = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("getColleges");
       SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("id", 2);
       Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(in);
   }

   public void doAnotherThing(){
       call = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("getClasses");
       SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("name", "Rahul");
       Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(in);
   }

}
```

Now, suppose a class calls `doSomething()` and the variable `call` is initialized with the procedure "**getColleges**". Before control moves to the next line of this method, `doAnotherThing()` gets called the `call` variable gets re-initialized to the procedure **"getClasses"**. Next, control executes the next line of `doSomething()` and tries to set the `id` parameter, but since call is now associated with the **"getClasses"** proc (which doesn't have the `id` parameter), the operation would fail.

Does being **"multi-threaded"** mean that the above race-condition won't happen for `SimpleJdbcCall`?

Comment: I suspect that is a type and should be **thread-safe**. The `SimpleJdbcCall` is thread-safe, meaning you can reuse a single instance from multiple threads. Your own code, however, isn't.

Comment: @M.Deinum "type" is a typo and should be "typo". Quite ironic, huh.

Comment: A `SimpleJdbcCall` *object* is thread-safe, aka a multi-threaded, reusable object, because it is an immutable object. Your `call` *field* however is not.

Comment: IMHO the **mutli-threaded** part is confusing and hints at that the `SimpleJdbcCall` itself is multi-threaded, using **thread-safe** would be clearer (as that is used for other things as well, like `JdbcTemplate`).